# Netmiko/Python script not dispaying output from multiple devices

Tags: python-3.x, freebsd, paramiko

When I run the script it only returns output from the first device.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.6
import netmiko
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import getpass
from getpass import getpass
exceptions = (netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoTimeoutException, netmiko.ssh_exception.NetMikoAuthenticationException)

     router = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '10.5.5.1',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': getpass(),
    'secret': getpass("Enable: "),
    'global_delay_factor': 2,
}

     switch = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': '10.5.5.2',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': getpass(),
    'secret': getpass("Enable: "),
    'global_delay_factor': 2,
}

list_of_devices = [router, switch]
for devices in list_of_devices:
    connector = ConnectHandler(**devices)


connector.enable()
print(connector)
output = connector.find_prompt()
output += connector.send_command('show ip arp', delay_factor=2)
print(output)

connector.disconnect()
```

Comment: for devices in list_of_devices:     # just below the "list_of_devices" line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have all of the Netmiko actions inside of the for loop. With your current code, you establish the connection on the first device, then move on to the second device and do something with it. You don't actually do anything with the first device (since the only thing inside the for loop is the ConnectHandler call):

So something like this (for the for-loop section):

```
list_of_devices = [router, switch]
for devices in list_of_devices:
    connector = ConnectHandler(**devices)
    connector.enable() 
    print(connector) 
    output = connector.find_prompt() 
    output += connector.send_command('show ip arp', delay_factor=2) 
    print(output)    
    connector.disconnect()
```